# vlcj black screen

Tags: java, video, vlcj

I am using vlcj api in my java application.My video is playing perfectly using that but there is an issue actually before playing the video a black screen appears what i exactly wants is  that instead of that black screen a some sort of image should appear before the start of video like in case of normal vlc player it's logo appear before the playing of video.

Comment: If you are modifying existing VLCJ sample test player code and you don't like to have a logo to appear every time you open a media when it is available, disable it in your code `mediaPlayer.enableLogo(false);` from `uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.events.VideoOutputEventListener.VideoOutputAvailable()` callback